Is there a closed form for $\int_0^1 \left \{xe^{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}\right \}dx$
I don't remember where this integral is from, but I have it written randomly on my old scratch paper:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left\{x\,{\rm e}^{\sin\left(1/x\right)}\right\}{\rm d}x
$$
Is there an actual closed-form answer for this integral ?.

$\tt WolframAlpha$ wouldn't answer

and $\tt Desmos$ gave me $0.352699865982$.


I tried letting $u = 1/x$, which clearly didn't lead to anything.
And then thought about the inequality of that function inside the fractional part, which also does no help$\dots$


Almost surely not. There are no obvious symmetries to exploit, it's of the form of a lot of unsolvable integrals, and the bounds (at least the upper bound of $1$) are entirely unnatural given the $\sin$ function.

What mean these brackets: ${}$ a floor function? With Mathematica numerics I have: $\int_0^1 x \exp \left(\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) , dx\approx 1.14216$

@MariuszIwaniuk I believe the brackets stand for the fractional part: ${x}:=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Dropping the fractional part brackets and making the substitution $z=-\frac 1x$, you might be able to obtain the integral of the resulting function by a clever enough application of the Residue Theorem - though I don't have it worked out. The difference between that integral and yours will be $\int_0^1\lfloor xe^{\sin(1/x)}\rfloor,dx$, which can be expressed as a finite sum, So I would say this has a moderately good chance of having a closed form.
